# Can "By means of" be used with a verb phrase?

Tags: idioms

The idiom "by means of" is ussualy used to explain the use of a tool or method with a noun phrase, but is it strictly correct to use it with a verb phrase?

For example:

- "The results are achieved by means of optimizing the parameters."
- "The distraction was created by means of setting off fireworks."

Comment: _Optimizing the parameters_ and _setting off fireworks_ are both **gerund** verb phrases, from gerund clauses, which are acting as noun phrases. Clauses are frequently deployed as noun phrases, and so are prepositional phrases.

Comment: What's wrong with "The results are achieved by optimizing the parameters."?